Why the html and css codes is not appearing in the page of a django form wizard page?
contest_selection.html:
{% extends "wizard_form.html" %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}`
{% load i18n %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Landing Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles/mainStyle.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles/LandingPageStyle.css' %}" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="Header">
            <img src="{% static 'images/###.png' %}" alt="######" class="headerimg1">
            <span>######################</span>
            <img src="{% static 'images/#####.png' %}" alt="######" class="headerImg2">
        </div>
        <hr />
        <br /><br />
        <div>
            <p class="subtitle" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Choose the <span style="color: #C83762;"> contests </span> you are registering in:</p>
            <br />
            <form method="post" >
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="container_box">
                    {% for contest in contests %}
                        <div>
                            <label class="checkbox-container">
                               <input type="radio" name="contest" value="{{ contest.id }}" id="checkbox{{ forloop.counter }}" data-color="{{ contest.color }}">
                                <span class="checkmark" id="checkbox{{ forloop.counter }}" data-color="{{ contest.color }}">
                                    <!-- color edit it later below-->
                                    <p style="font-weight: 800; font-size: 24px;">{{ contest.name.split('-')[0] }}-<span style="color:black;">{{ contest.name.split('-')[1] }}</span></p>
                                    <p>{{ contest.description }}</p>
                                </span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Next</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <br />
        <div class="footer">
            <span>Strategic partner</span>
            <img src="{% static 'images/#####.png' %}" alt="#######">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
            const radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"][name="contest"]');
            radioButtons.forEach(radio => {
                radio.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
                    radioButtons.forEach(rb => {
                        const checkmark = rb.nextElementSibling;
                        if (rb.checked) {
                            checkmark.style.borderColor = rb.getAttribute('data-color');
                        } else {
                            checkmark.style.borderColor = 'rgb(217, 217, 217)';
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
   </script>
</body>
   </html>

I tried to put HTML Content within {% block content %}: The entire HTML content, including the header, footer, and other elements, be within the {% block content %} tag. but it didnt work. do you have any idea?

I'd need to see your wizard_form.html, but standard practice is to put all those elements (header, footer, etc..) in the base template, which I guess is wizard_form.html since that is what you are extending.  The wizard_form.html should have {% block content %}{% endblock content %}, then in your contest_selection.html you would include only what you want to add to the template: {% block content %}Include the specific contest_selection content here{% endblock content %}.  Django takes your base template and puts that content where the base template has {% block cont...

Is your wizard_form.html extending another template, like base.html or layout.html? If so, you don’t need to repeat all the HTML. The base template should include the  tag, and you can use additional blocks within it to add more tags. You usually use a block named "content" or similar in the base template for specific page content. If you're not seeing anything on the page, make sure you’re correctly extending the templates.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
